# Using Get-Content inside Get-Service

Tags: server, automation, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a list of servers (server.txt), and I want to get the service status of "Nimsoft Robot Watcher" of all the servers.

I tried the code:

```bsh
$text1 = Get-Content server.txt
foreach ($text1 in Get-Content server.txt)
{
    $text=$text1
}
Get-Service -ComputerName $text -DisplayName "Nimsoft Robot Watcher"
```

But only the status for the first server gets displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you currently have will replace the value of `$text` with each iteration, leaving you with just the last name after the loop completes.

Either put `Get-Service` inside the loop

```bsh
foreach ($text in Get-Content server.txt) {
    Get-Service -ComputerName $text -DisplayName "Nimsoft Robot Watcher"
}
```

or collect the hosts in an array and pass that to `Get-Service`

```bsh
$text = Get-Content server.txt
Get-Service -ComputerName $text -DisplayName "Nimsoft Robot Watcher"
```

Comment: I need to add the server name as well, before the services, can you please suggest something for that?

Comment: The objects returned by `Get-Service` have a property `MachineName`.

Comment: how can it be used? i am quite new to powershell actually

Comment: `... | Select-Object MachineName, DisplayName, Status`